# Is there a fix to an issue of going to link on deviantArt?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

So I have a flash game (written in AS3, of course), and written with a whole bunch of classes. One certain class links to a page with

```
navigateToURL(new URLRequest("websitehere"), "_blank");
```

The class works fine and flawlessly when I test movie, and when I run the published file. However, when I post it on deviantArt, the entire class doesn't execute (it's almost as if it didn't exist). I suspect it's because of the navigateToURL command since I vaguely remember reading somewhere that deviantArt doesn't allow navigateToURL commands. I tested it with a test, though, that had only a navigateToURL function, and it worked.

Anyways, is there a fix for this issue or some way around it?
I can post the deviantArt link to the flash game, as well as the coding to the actual flash file and its classes if it's necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what I did, but when I reuploaded the .swf file (I tried it a couple of times before to no avail), the problem was solved.